# How can i bypass cors error on the client side when building web apps?

Tags: javascript, api, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make a get request to githubjobs API in my nuxt app using axios. I have axios properly setup and configured. Here is the action I want to dispatch:

```
  async defaultJobsFetch({commit}){
    try{
      const res = await axios.get('https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?location=new+york')
      const jobs = res.data;
      commit('getJobs', jobs)
    }catch(error){
      commit("errored");
      console.log(error)
    }
    finally{
      commit('changeLoading')
    }
  },
```

I tried using https://cors-anywhere.herokupp.com/ too, but I still get an error 403 forbidden

I noticed it works fine on my local machine but when i deploy, and try to load the deployed app, I don’t get a response back, i get that 403 error instead. The app is hosted on heroku, http://hubjobs.herokuapp.com, check the console when you visit the site to see the error

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to use a chrome extension like CORS unblock or try having this in the header :

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 0):

You can try [cors.bridged.cc](https://cors.bridged.cc/) instead of [cors-anywhere.herokupp.com](http://cors-anywhere.herokupp.com)