# i am getting error while fetching this api

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, blockchain, uniswap

Basically i am calling uniswap widget in react app

**https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/uniswap/all.json**
i am getting error while fetching this api
but when i am calling thi api it's giving me error
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rujrc.png)

i have tried request headers in axios i am calling this widget in react.

i am getting response in postmen but can't fetch data in app

it's giving me **404 bad request** and **strict-origin-when-cross-origin**

but i can't fetch tokenList from this api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i bypass cors error on the client side when building web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224200/how-can-i-bypass-cors-error-on-the-client-side-when-building-web-apps)